# Android How to reduce Memory size while doing the frame animation

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-animation

I am performing the frame animation and using the images having 550*360 resolution. I have read somewhere that large images should be scaled to minimum size and resolution as 1 pixels takes 4 byte of space into a memory.

I am performing the frame by frame animation but this is causing me a large size growth in memory As I checked it from the android studio memory analyzer tool and some times it crash due to out of memory error.

**I know that this is due to huge size of images which gets load into the memory but the question are as below :**

1. What are the safe way to load images into memory with out taking too much space.?
2. How Can I do frame animation with out getting OOM error
3. Let suppose that the animation which I am using is working although taking too much space into memory , but the animations ends up with out any problem, so here is the thing , after performing animation How can I de-load the images from the memory , as they have performed their animation task now they are useless ?

Please tell me the way and provide source code , if not you can answer , then please at least tell me how can I do what I have stated in point number 3. As this one is easy.

**Edit Here is how I am doing my animation (Frame by Frame)**

```
public abstract class AnimationDrawableCallback implements Drawable.Callback {


private Drawable mLastFrame;


private Drawable.Callback mWrappedCallback;

/**
 * Flag to ensure that {@link #onAnimationComplete()} is called only once, since
 * {@link #invalidateDrawable(Drawable)} may be called multiple times.
 */
private boolean mIsCallbackTriggered = false;


public AnimationDrawableCallback(AnimationDrawable animationDrawable, Drawable.Callback callback) {
    mLastFrame = animationDrawable.getFrame(animationDrawable.getNumberOfFrames() - 1);
    mWrappedCallback = callback;
}

@Override
public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
    if (mWrappedCallback != null) {
        mWrappedCallback.invalidateDrawable(who);
    }

    if (!mIsCallbackTriggered && mLastFrame != null && mLastFrame.equals(who.getCurrent())) {
        mIsCallbackTriggered = true;
        onAnimationComplete();
    }
}

@Override
public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
    if (mWrappedCallback != null) {
        mWrappedCallback.scheduleDrawable(who, what, when);
    }
}

@Override
public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
    if (mWrappedCallback != null) {
        mWrappedCallback.unscheduleDrawable(who, what);
    }
}




public abstract void onAnimationComplete();
```

}

**Dialog Class AS I am showing my animation In Dialog.**

```
    public class AnimationDialog extends Dialog  {


    public Activity c;
  //  public Dialog dialog;
//    public Button yes, no;
    ImageView mImageView;
    int mDrawable;
    AnimationDrawable countdownAnimation;
    Animation animationFalling;
    public AnimationDialog(Activity a, int drawable) {
        super(a);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = a;
        this.mDrawable = drawable;
        getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogAnimation);
       // AnimationDialog.this.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogSlideAnim;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnCancelListener(OnCancelListener listener) {
        super.setOnCancelListener(listener);
        countdownAnimation = null;
        animationFalling = null;
        mImageView = null;
        c = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        super.dismiss();
        countdownAnimation = null;
        animationFalling = null;
        mImageView = null;
        c = null;
 //       dialog = null;



    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        getWindow().setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

        //this.setCancelable(false);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_animation);

        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(mDrawable);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 100ms
                ((AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getBackground()).start();
                countdownAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getBackground();
                countdownAnimation.setCallback(new AnimationDrawableCallback(countdownAnimation, mImageView) {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationComplete() {
                        // TODO Do something.
//                        Toast.makeText(c, "Animation Ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
                        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
                        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.secondry_frame);
                        animationFalling = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.anim_falling);
                        rl.startAnimation(animationFalling);
                        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                countdownAnimation = null;
                                animationFalling=null;
                                countdownAnimation = null;
                                AnimationDialog.this.cancel();
                                dismiss();
                               // AnimationDialog.this.dismiss();
//                                countdownAnimation = null;

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                countdownAnimation.start();

                // Toast.makeText(Alif.this,"Please start from the word Top",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, 1500);
   }
  }
```

**and in drawable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_1"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_2"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_3"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_4"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_5"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_6"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_7"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_8"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_9"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_10"
    android:duration="300" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_11"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_12"
    android:duration="300" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_13"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_14"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_15"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_16"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_17"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_18"
    android:duration="300" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/rolling_19"
    android:duration="300" />
```

**and In activity I am calling it like**

```
 animationDialog = new AnimationDialog(Main.this, R.drawable.my_animation);
                            animationDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement something on your onDestroy method . I mean you should set the reference of animation to the null in onDestroy. this is what I am thinking right now , becuase You have not provide proper detail

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

//set your refernce of animation class or what ever you using to null

}
```

Comment: well I know about this and My basic idea was also this , but it is not helping

Answer (score 0):

You should release old images to free the memory and load them only when they are about to show.
For example, the ViewPager in Android by default loads in memory only 3 pages: the visible one, the previous and the next.
When you swipe to next page, the previous will be deleted, and the new-next will be loaded.

Also, can you provide the source of how you load the images and how you perform the animation?

Comment: How can I release the old images to free memory ?

Comment: Depends on how you create and store them. Can you post the creation code and animation code?

Comment: I have Updated my  question , check it now

Comment: Oooh... This is a sprite animation. Can you show me the animation itself? Maybe it is possible to make it another way.
A .gif file, for example, or a set of frames in one image?

Comment: I cant , I can not do this cause I do not know , its just frame by frame animation , gives you feel that we are mving something in imageview

Comment: You can concat all frames into one image, upload it to an image hosting and post here the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97656/discussion-between-genia-and-allay-khalil).

Comment: then how it is going to help you

Comment: I want to see the animation. Maybe it is possible to make it another way, instead of using frames.